# How can I display the new randomly generated data in an alv report?

Tags: abap

I have this program to generate data randomly, what I need is, display the new generated data as alv report/in table format. How can i make this? I also want to display the names of fields and thier data type in table format. can someone help please?

[image]

```html
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report Z_THIRD_REPORT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
REPORT Z_THIRD_REPORT.

TABLES: DFIES,
  X030L.

DATA: BEGIN OF INTTAB OCCURS 100.
  INCLUDE STRUCTURE DFIES.
DATA: END OF INTTAB.

DATA: FIELD_DATA_TYPE TYPE DFIES-DATATYPE,
      NUM_RECORDS TYPE I.

*PARAMETERS: p_taname TYPE DDOBJNAME OBLIGATORY.
PARAMETERS: TABLENM TYPE dd02l-tabname OBLIGATORY,
            RECORDS TYPE I.

SELECT * FROM dd02l INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_tables)
  WHERE ( tabname LIKE 'Z%' OR tabname LIKE 'Y%' )
    AND as4local = 'A'
    AND tabclass IN ('TRANSP', 'INTTAB').

CALL FUNCTION 'DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET'
EXPORTING
  tabname = TABLENM
  LANGU   = SY-LANGU
TABLES
  DFIES_TAB = INTTAB
EXCEPTIONS
  NOT_FOUND      = 1
  INTERNAL_ERROR = 2
  OTHERS         = 3.

IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  WRITE:/ 'Field name not found'.
ELSE.
  WRITE:/ 'Fields',  'Data Type'.  " Column headers
  LOOP AT INTTAB.
    FIELD_DATA_TYPE = INTTAB-DATATYPE.  " Store the data type in FIELD_DATA_TYPE.
    WRITE:/  INTTAB-FIELDNAME, FIELD_DATA_TYPE.

    " Generate random data for each field based on its data type
    PERFORM generate_random_data USING INTTAB-FIELDNAME FIELD_DATA_TYPE RECORDS.

  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.

FORM generate_random_data
  USING
    p_fieldname TYPE DFIES-FIELDNAME
    p_datatype   TYPE DFIES-DATATYPE
    p_records    TYPE I.

  DATA: random_value TYPE STRING,
        counter      TYPE I.

  LOOP AT INTTAB WHERE FIELDNAME = p_fieldname AND DATATYPE = p_datatype.
    DO p_records TIMES.
      " Create unique values based on field name and counter
      counter = counter + 1.
      random_value = |{ p_fieldname }_{ counter }|.

      WRITE: / p_fieldname, random_value.
    ENDDO.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDFORM.
```

In the image you can see the result for the generated data ( 3 records), it is a mess.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your data on a internal table. Then you can use CL_SALV.

```
data: lo_salv type ref to cl_salv_table.

  call method cl_salv_table=>factory
   IMPORTING
    R_SALV_TABLE = lo_salv
   changing
    t_table = lt_itab.

  lo_salv->display( ).
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is the problem, how to save the data in internal table? In you code lt_itab is the internal table, true? But how can create it? I get error that lt_itab is unknown.

Comment: I assume that you are looking this complete example: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/11/dynamic-internal-table-iilustrated-with-an-example-of-creating-the-transpose-of-internal-table/